# simple java regex throwing illegalstateexception

Tags: java, regex, illegalstateexception

Im trying to do a quick sanity check... and its failing. Here is my code -

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "a";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(a)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        System.out.println("group 1: " +m.group(1));
    } 
}
```

And what I would expect is to see `group 1: a`. But instead I get an `IllegalStateException: no match found` and I have no idea why.

Edit: I also tries printing out `groupCount()` and it says there is 1.

Answer (score 15):

You need to invoke `m.find()` or `m.matches()` first to be able to use `m.group`.

- `find` can be used to find each substring that matches your pattern (used mainly in situations where there is more than one match)
- `matches` will check if entire string matches your pattern so you wont even need to add `^` and `$` in your pattern.

We can also use `m.lookingAt()` but for now lets skip its description (you can read it in documentation).

Answer (score 4):

Use [Matcher#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) or [Matcher#find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) prior to invoking `Matcher.group(int)`

```
if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("group 1: " +m.group(1));
}
```

In this case `Matcher#find` is more appropriate as `Matcher#matches` matches the complete `String` (making the anchor characters redundant in the matching expression)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for `Matcher`. You will see that "attempting to query any part of it before a successful match will cause an IllegalStateException to be thrown".

Wrap your `group(1)` call with `if (matcher.find()) {}` to resolve this problem.