# Java Pattern does not match RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Java code that is supposed to extract a url from a String object

```
public static void main() {
    String text = "Link to https://some.domain.com/subfolder?sometext is     available";
    String regex = "https://some\\.domain\\.com/subfolder[^ ]*";
    Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    Matcher m = urlPattern.matcher(text);

    String url = m.group();

    System.out.println(url);

    return;
}
```

However, there is no match and the code fails with `IllegalStateException`.

What is wrong with the RegEx?

Comment: String regex = "https:\/\/some\\.domain\\.com/subfolder[^ ]*";

Comment: @lordkain Why do you want to escape the slashes?

Comment: @lordkain that is an illegal escape sequence. Besides, I also tried simply `https.*` which also fails.

Comment: I don't think you can use 'group' without calling find or matches methods first.

Comment: if(m.matches()){
      String url = m.group();
 
      System.out.println(url);
     }                                                                                                                                      
IllegalStateException - If no match has yet been attempted, or if the previous match operation failed

Comment: @Sanka no; `.matches()` is a misnomer, see my answer

Comment: https://regex101.com/ says your regex should be:
https:\/\/some\.domain\.com\/subfolder[^ ]*
This is without escaping for java, so all backslashes should be escaped by a backslash as well...
So that makes it `"https:\\/\\/some\\.domain\\.com\\/subfolder[^ ]*"`

Comment: Another dupe source - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257561/simple-java-regex-throwing-illegalstateexception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't ask a `Matcher` to give a `.group()` unless you have called a method which asks the `Matcher` to operate on the input: one of `.find()` (preferred), `.lookingAt()` or `.matches()`.

This is why you get an `IllegalStateException`.

As to the differences between the three, while the javadoc tells it all, just a quick reminder:

- `.find()` does "real" regex matching: it will try and match the regex anywhere in the input text;
- `.lookingAt()` adds the constraint that the pattern should match at the beginning of the input text;
- `.matches()` is a misnomer since in addition to the constraint imposed by `.lookingAt()`, it also required that *the full input text* (the "entire region" in the javadoc) is matched.

Please also recall that those three methods return a boolean depending on whether the match was successful; if the result is `false`, you can't `.group()`.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to call `m.find()` or `m.matches()`. This is mandatory, otherwise `group()` does not work.

The `find()` should return `true` if the pattern is matched. Only in this case `group()` will return what you are expecting.

So, modify your code as following:

```
....
if (!m.find()) {
    return;
}
String url = m.group();
...
```

EDIT
Concerning to what method to call: `find()` or `matches()`. 
`find()` looks for the pattern in part of string, `matches()` matches full string. They relate like `contains()` and `equals()` of strings.

I personally prefer to use `find()` because in this case the regex fully defines the behavior. If I want to match full string I use `^` and `$`.

Comment: You forgot `.lookingAt()`

Answer (score 2):

Since `m.group()`

> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

you have to call `m.matches()` or `m.find()` before using `m.group()`.