# RegEx with capturing groups not working in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have strings that have a pattern like the following ones:

- **PSHELF**-**2**[PSHELF-**MF-6RU**]
- **SHELF**-**5**[SHELF-**M6**]
- **SHELF**-**6**[SHELF-**M15**]
- **SHELF**-**6**[SHELF-**M15**]

I'd like to get the info highlighted.
To do so I use the following regex:

```
(.*SHELF)-(.*)\[.*SHELF-(.*)\]
```

I tested it with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8uHYgP/1/)

If I try to implement the same login on **Java**

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*SHELF)-(.*)\\[.*SHELF-(.*)\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
String group1 = matcher.group(1);
String group2 = matcher.group(2);
String group3 = matcher.group(3);
```

I got the following error:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

Why is that?

Comment: You need to call `matcher.find()` first and if it returned true the groups will be initialized and accessible. From the JavaDoc on `group(int)`: " If no match has yet been _attempted_ ..." - and on `find()`: "If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.".

Comment: or `if (matcher.matches()) { matcher.group(1);}`

Comment: Perhaps like `([A-Z]+)-\d+\[\1-([A-Z\d]+(?:-[A-Z\d]+)?)\]` and use capturing group 1 and 2 [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4DSd28/1)

Answer (score -1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257561/simple-java-regex-throwing-illegalstateexception) answers your original question.

---

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/66r4PK/1) creates capturing groups and returns your desired outputs in multiple forms:

```
(([A-Z]+)-([0-9]+))\[([A-Z]+)-([A-Z0-9-]+)(\])
```

which you can additionally simplify it, if you wish.

[image]

#### Java Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(([A-Z]+)-([0-9]+))\\[([A-Z]+)-([A-Z0-9-]+)(\\])";
final String string = "PSHELF-2[PSHELF-MF-6RU]\n"
     + "SHELF-5[SHELF-M6]\n"
     + "SHELF-6[SHELF-M15]\n"
     + "SHELF-6[SHELF-M15]";
final String subst = "\\1 \\4";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(([A-Z]+)-([0-9]+))\[([A-Z]+)-([A-Z0-9-]+)(\])/gm;
const str = `PSHELF-2[PSHELF-MF-6RU]
SHELF-5[SHELF-M6]
SHELF-6[SHELF-M15]
SHELF-6[SHELF-M15]`;
const subst = `\nGroup 1: $1\nGroup 2: $2\nGroup3: $3\nGroup 4: $4\nGroup 5: $5`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Basic Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the expression performance using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = 'PSHELF-2[PSHELF-MF-6RU]';
 const regex = /(([A-Z]+)-([0-9]+))\[([A-Z]+)-([A-Z0-9-]+)(\])/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "\nGroup #1: $1\nGroup #2: $2 \nGroup #3: $3 \nGroup #4: $4\nGroup #5: $5\n");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: That is not the reason for OPs `IllegalStateException`. OP already has a working regex.

Comment: Using your regex with OPs code will also cause an `IllegalStateException`.